# how to set a specific value from the array for a spinner based on another spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my application I have two spinners (occupation, sub-occupation) where the first spinner is populated from an array of string and the second spinner is populated based on the value selected in the first spinner.

The selected values of both spinners are stored in SQLite database. After saving the user can edit the record, so while displaying the records to edit I want to display the specific values on the spinner that the user last selected.

When I try doing so the first spinner value is set correctly, but I'm not able to set the second spinner value. It always displays the first value in the array for that spinner.

Here is the code for assigning value to spinners in EDIT page:

```
    if (bundlevalue.get(21).equalsIgnoreCase("Salaried")) {
        spin_occupation.setSelection(0);
        if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Others"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(4);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Police"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(1);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Legal Profession"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(2);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Central/State Government"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(3);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(0);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
     else if (bundlevalue.get(21).equalsIgnoreCase(
            "Self employed non professional")) {
        spin_occupation.setSelection(1);
        if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Others"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(5);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Travel Agent /Telecommunication Service/Tours&Travels"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(1);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Restaurant/Hotels/Resorts"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(2);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Retail Stores"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(3);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if(bundlevalue.get(22).equalsIgnoreCase("Money Changers/Money Lenders/Real Estate"))
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(4);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            spin_subOccu.setSelection(0);
            occuSubArrayAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

What is wrong with my code? Could somebody please explain?

Please help!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: do your sub_spinner has multiple values to show ?

Comment: @r4jiv007 yes! the value depends on the first spinner..

Answer (score 0):

set OnItemClickListener() to your super_spinner and when any item is selected try to change the Values of Adapter you passed to your sub_spinner.

```
super_spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // change adapter values of sub_spinner here !!
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes that i am doing in the same way that you have shown...but i want to show the only value that is saved in the database on the spinner like i have shown in my code... i am getting the correct arrays based on first spinner value but i need to display the correct value from that array on the spinner.....which is not happening...

Answer (score 0):

update the array list of second spinner in 1st spinner setOnItemSelectedListener

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                string str=spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(str.equals("spinner item"))//spinner item is selected item of spinner1
                {
                    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array1);

             spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);//pass this updated adapter1 to second spinner
                }else if{
               ArrayAdapter<String>adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array2);

             spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    }
        }
```

Comment: Yes that i am doing in the same way that you have shown...but i want to show the only value that is saved in the database on the spinner like i have shown in my code... i am getting the correct arrays based on first spinner value but i need to display the correct value from that array on the spinner.....which is not happening...